# resample date end of month match with date from original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, resample

I have data that i want to resample use end of month based on original df but when i use df.resample('M').last(). the end of month date that i got is different from original df.
see the asterix marks.  *2005-12-31* should be >> *2005-12-29*. any suggestion ? what parameter should i add into .resample() ?

orginal df =

```
DATE
2005-12-27    1161.707
2005-12-28    1164.143
*2005-12-29    1162.635*
2006-01-02    1171.709
2006-01-03    1184.690
2006-01-04    1211.699
```

test_resample = df.resample('M').last()

```
DATE
2005-11-30    1096.641
*2005-12-31    1162.635*
2006-01-31    1232.321
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'2005-12-27': 1161.707,
        '2005-12-28': 1164.143,
        '2005-12-29': 1162.635,
        '2006-01-02': 1171.709,
        '2006-01-03': 1184.69,
        '2006-01-04': 1211.699}
s = pd.Series(data)
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)
```

output(`s`):

```
2005-12-27    1161.707
2005-12-28    1164.143
2005-12-29    1162.635
2006-01-02    1171.709
2006-01-03    1184.690
2006-01-04    1211.699
dtype: float64
```

**Code**

```
s.groupby(s.index.to_period('M')).tail(1)
```

output:

```
2005-12-29    1162.635
2006-01-04    1211.699
dtype: float64
```

If `s` is not sorted by time order, sort index

Comment: Thanks Panda Kim.. it solve the problem.. many thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly with `resample`, you should instead [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) after temporarily resetting the index:

```
(df.reset_index()
   .groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))
   .agg({'DATE': 'last', 'value': 'last'})
   .set_index('DATE')
)
```

Output:

```
               value
DATE                
2005-12-29  1162.635
2006-01-04  1211.699
```

Comment: HI mozway,, sorry for keep asking if i have multiple columns. what should i do ?             cols = df.columns.tolist(),                                                                                          
 test = df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).agg({'DATE': 'last', cols: 'last' }).set_index('DATE')